# Looping through Facebook and instagram

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I got small problem, atm im working with displaying social network feed on my website, like facebook and instagram, here is the problem, when i post something, i do it from my phone, so i share it both on facebook and instagram at the same time, which means i got some duplicate on website feed, the text from facebook is the same as instagram caption text. Now what i want to do is that when facebook text is the same as instagram caption text. I dont want to display facebook post, anyone could help me with this ? here is the code

CONTROLLER:

```
        //Instagram
        posts.AddRange((from InstagramMedia media in response.Body.Data
                        select new NewsViewModel
                        {
                            InstagramLink = media.Link,
                            Images = media.Standard,
                            Caption = media.CaptionText,
                            DateAdded = media.Created,
                            InstagramDateTimeAdded = media.Created,
                            LikesCount = media.LikeCount,
                            ProfilePicture = media.User.ProfilePicture


                        })
                                    .ToList());
        //Facebook
        posts.AddRange((from FacebookPost media in responseFB.Body.Data
                        select new NewsViewModel
                        {
                           FaceBookText = media.Message,
                           DateAdded = media.CreatedTime,
                           FacebookDateTimeAdded = media.CreatedTime,
                           FacebookStory = media.Story,
                           FacebookId = media.Id
                       }).ToList());


        return View(posts);`
```

and here is the view

```
            @if(tweet.FacebookStory != null)
            {
                <div class="facebookFeed-container mb-3 mt-3">
                    <a href="https://facebook.com/iosoftab" target="_blank">
                        <img src="~/Content/img/logos/IosoftFbLogo.png" class="mt-2 ml-2" style="width:40px;" />
                        <span style="color:#5572A9;font-weight:600;position:relative;top:5px; left:10px;">IOSoft AB</span>
                    </a>
                    <hr style="margin-top:5px;" />
                    <p style="padding:10px;
                        overflow-wrap: break-word;
                        word-wrap: break-word;">
                        @tweet.FacebookStory
                    </p>
                    <hr />
                    <div class="bottom-news-facebook">
                        <a href="https://facebook.com/@tweet.FacebookId" target="_blank"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up fa-2x ml-3"></i></a>
                        <span style="float:right;color:#5572A9" class="mr-3">@tweet.DateAdded.ToLongDateString() @tweet.DateAdded.ToShortTimeString()</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
            @if(tweet.Caption != null)
            {
                <div class="instagramFeed-container mb-3 mt-3">
                    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/iosoft/" target="_blank">
                        <img src="@tweet.ProfilePicture" class="mt-2 ml-2" style="width:40px;" />
                        <span style="color:#545454;font-weight:600;position:relative;top:7px; left:10px;">iosoft</span>
                    </a>
                    <img src="@tweet.Images" style="width:100%; margin-top:15px;margin-bottom:10px;" />
                    <div class="bottom-news-instagram">
                        <a href="@tweet.InstagramLink" target="_blank"><i class="far fa-heart fa-2x"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <p style="padding:10px;
                        overflow-wrap: break-word;
                        word-wrap: break-word;">
                        <span style="font-weight:600">iosoft</span> @tweet.Caption
                    </p>
                    <hr />
                    <div class="instagram-bottom-timeLikes">
                        <span style="font-weight:600;margin-left:10px;">@tweet.LikesCount gilla-markeringar</span>
                        <span style="float:right;color:#5572A9" class="mr-3">@tweet.InstagramDateTimeAdded.AddHours(1)</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
            @if (tweet.FaceBookText != null && tweet.FaceBookText != tweet.Caption)
            {
                <div class="facebookFeed-container mb-3 mt-3">
                    <a href="https://facebook.com/iosoftab" target="_blank">
                        <img src="~/Content/img/logos/IosoftFbLogo.png" class="mt-2 ml-2" style="width:40px;" />
                        <span style="color:#5572A9;font-weight:600;position:relative;top:5px; left:10px;">IOSoft AB</span>
                    </a>
                    <hr style="margin-top:5px;" />
                    <p style="padding:10px;
                        overflow-wrap: break-word;
                        word-wrap: break-word;">
                        @tweet.FaceBookText
                    </p>
                    <hr />
                    <div class="bottom-news-facebook">
                        <a href="https://facebook.com/@tweet.FacebookId" target="_blank"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up fa-2x ml-3"></i></a>
                        <span style="float:right;color:#5572A9" class="mr-3">@tweet.FacebookDateTimeAdded</span>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            }
        </div>`
```

but i still see facebook posts, anyone know why?
/Patryk

Comment: [Please don't add "Thank you"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/133056).

Comment: @UweKeim why not?

Comment: Click my magic link and you will find out why!

Comment: Sorry! did not know that ^^

Answer (score 0):

try tweet.FaceBookText != null && tweet.FaceBookText.ToLower() != tweet.Caption.ToLower()

Comment: Why should he try this?

Comment: He should add it because it is a common practice when comparing strings, but this will not resolve his issue. His problem is he is looping through post which are aggregate of instagram and fb post and he is comparing current element to it self but different property if you understand what I am saying